# Cumulative distinct count filtered by last value - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct-values

I am trying to come up with exactly the same answer as here:

[Cumulative distinct count filtered by last value - DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021336/cumulative-distinct-count-filtered-by-last-value-dax)

but in SQL Server. For convenience I am copying the whole problem description.

I have a dataset:

```
month   name    flag
1       abc     TRUE
2       xyz     TRUE
3       abc     TRUE
4       xyz     TRUE
5       abc     FALSE
6       abc     TRUE
```

I want to calculate month-cumulative distinct count of 'name' filtered by last 'flag' value (TRUE). I.e. I want to have a result:

```
month   count
1       1
2       2
3       2
4       2
5       1
6       2
```

In months 5 and 6 'abc' should be excluded because the flag switched to 'FALSE' in month 5.

I am thinking about using "over" clause with "partition by" but I don't have any experience here so it's a struggle for me.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the last row in exemplary source data.
was:
6       abc     FALSE
is:
6       abc     TRUE

And the last row in output data.
Was:
6       1
is:
6       2

It might have not been obivous from the description that it should work this way and the proposed answer does not solve this problem.

**UPDATE 2**

I have managed to create a query that gives the result but it's ugly and I think could be shrinked by using `over` clause. Can you help me with that?

```
select t5.month_current, count(*) as count from
    (select t3.month month_current, t4.month months_until_current, t3.name, t4.flag from
        (select name ,month from
            (select distinct name
                from Source_data) t1
            ,(select distinct month
                from Source_data) t2) t3
        left join
        Source_data t4
        on t3.name = t4.name and t3.month >= t4.month) t5
    inner join
    (select t3.month month_current, max(t4.month) real_max_month_until_current, t3.name from
        (select name ,month from
            (select distinct name
                from Source_data) t1
            ,(select distinct month
                from Source_data) t2) t3
        left join
        Source_data t4
        on t3.name = t4.name and t3.month >= t4.month
            group by
                t3.month, t3.name) t6
    on t5.month_current = t6.month_current
        and t5.months_until_current = t6.real_max_month_until_current
        and t5.name = t6.name
            where t5.flag = 'TRUE'
                group by t5.month_current
```

Comment: The flag doesn't make sense to me.  What happens if `abc` appears again with a flag of `true`?

Comment: It's a field that changes the logic. In terms of meaning we can try to think of many scenarios, I believe. For example name is an LED ID and flag indicates whether it's been switched on (TRUE) or off (FALSE). And you are trying to find out how many LEDs were switched on in a given month (ones with updated status).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a cumulative distinct count as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by month) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by month) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

I don't understand the logic for incorporating the flag.

You can replicate the results in the question by incorporating the flag:

```
      select t.*,
             sum(case when seqnum = 1 and flag = 'true' then 1
                      when seqnum = 1 and flag = 'false' then -1
                      else 0
                 end) over (order by month) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by name, flag order by month) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t;
```

Comment: hi Gordon - I really like your fist snippet above. I know t-sql is always getting more functionality - is your first snippet above still the quickest way to do rolling distinct counts, or has microsoft built this functionality into one of it latest window functions?

Comment: @whytheq . . . SQL Server (at least some versions) support `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as a window function.  I don't know if it is any faster than the version in this answer.

Comment: Cheers Gordon - we're using 2016 version - I'll give it a try.